# How to apply a lot of images to the plane segments in Three.js

Tags: javascript, geometry, three.js, textures, webgl

I wonder, if you set more segements in Geometry instance of `THREE.JS` for e.g.:

```
new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1, 10, 10);
```

You will see that your plane is divided (if to turn on the wireframe mode) into 10x10 parts.

Is it possible to apply some generated images (for e.g. map fragments) and to each segment of plane (or other geometry object) with the following image (part of map)?

I want just to create one plane and apply many images to each segment of it (of course with the preparing the cound segements perviously), so it would look like a map.

If it's possible, how to do it?
I'm new to the `WebGL/THREE.JS`, so I need help.

PS The main thing is that I'm NOT asking about repeated segments with the same texture, but about using a lot of different textures for one geometry object and apply them to its segments.

Thanks for a piece of advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overwrite UVs to map image on the face

```
geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].push([
        new THREE.Vector2( 0,0 ),
        new THREE.Vector2( 0,1 ),
        new THREE.Vector2( 1,1 ),    
        new THREE.Vector2( 1,0 ),    
]);
```

and set materialIndex for the face.

```
geometry.faces[i].materialIndex = i;
materials.push(material);
```

[Full example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fy3j/7/)

Comment: wow! I even don't know about such technuque... UV? Need to reed. Thanks a lot! :)